# Argparse "arguments are required" error even when I have a default value set

Tags: python, argparse

I'm a little confused about the use of the `default` keyword argument for the `add_argument()` method in argparse. Here's a really simple script I ran to see how arguments are parsed:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('some_string', default = 'hello world')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.some_string)
```

When I run this in my terminal and provide an argument, it parses correctly:

```
$ python argparse_test.py "hello world"
> hello world
```

When I run this in my terminal and **omit** an argument, I get an error:

```
$ python argparse_test.py
> argparse_test.py: error: the following arguments are required: some_string
```

Am I overlooking something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying a positional argument, which are required. You probably wanted a keyword argument instead, something like `--some_string`. If you have enough unique letters, you may also wanna specify an alias for it, like `-s`. Now you can run it like

- python argparse_test.py
- python argparse_test.py --some_string="hello world"

Comment: That's it! Thank you